# Hide refinement tabs in Google CSE?

Tags: javascript, google-custom-search

Is there a way to hide the refinement tab(s) in a [Google Custom Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Custom_Search_Engine#Custom_Search_Engine) (CSE)?

I'm using the [Ajax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) CSE and I don't want/have refinements. Therefore a single tab is pretty useless and disturbing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `.gsc-tabsArea { display: none; }` style seems to work. Is that allowed?